# Error when cross compiling shared so which depends on another so

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, gnu

I am trying to cross compile my application for a arm based system.

I have 2 libraries compiled in the following way:

```
$ gcc -shared --sysroot=$DIR_PATH -o $LIBPATH/libfoo.so foo.o
$ gcc -shared --sysroot=$DIR_PATH -o $LIBPATH/libbar.so bar.o
```

A third library is compiled:

```
gcc -shared -o $LIBPATH/libfoobar.so --sysroot=$DIR_PATH -L$LIBPATH -Wl,rpath=$RUN_TIME_PATH foobar.o -lfoo -lbar
```

Then finally I compile a binary:

```
gcc -o app --sysroot=$DIR_PATH -L$LIBPATH -Wl,rpath=$RUN_TIME_PATH app.o -lfoobar
```

However when compiling app I get

```
warning: libfoo.so, needed by libfoobar.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Comment: Surely you mean, when linking `app` you get that error, not when compiling `app.o`?

Comment: We can't help you because you haven't told us (a) what directory the various libraries are in, and (b) what the value of `$LIBPATH` is.  If the libraries are not in `$LIBPATH` then that's the problem.  If they are in the current working directory, and that's different than `$LIBPATH`, then you need to add `-L.` to your link line to the linker can find them.

Comment: Yes. I mean app.

Comment: LIBPATH=/home/user/proj_dir/ShOb  RUN_TIME_PATH=/usr/lib (on the target)

Comment: The runtime path isn't relevant to this problem because that only comes into effect when you run the program.  Here you're linking the program.  You didn't tell us what the working directory is where the link command is invoked.  Is it `/home/user/proj_dir/ShOb`?  If not, then that's your problem because your libraries are in the local directory but the local directory isn't given to the linker as a place to look for libraries (via `-L`).

Comment: Working directory from where make is invoked is: /home/user/proj_dir/. All *.so files are located in: /home/user/proj_dir/SObj which = LIBPATH

Comment: That's not what your example shows.  You show `gcc ... -o libfoo.so` so if your working directory is `/home/user/proj_dir` then the file will be `/home/user/proj_dir/libfoo.so` not `/home/user/proj_dir/SObj/libfoo.so` (also above you say that LIBOBJ is `/home/user/proj_dir/ShOb` and here you say it's `/home/user/proj_dir/SObj`... which is right?)  We cannot help if the information provided is not precisely accurate.  Please edit your question and put in all the information, and re-read it carefully to make sure there are no typos or other mistakes.

Comment: If the libraries do exist in the current directory then I already provided the most likely solution above: add `-L.` to your link line so that the linker will look in the current working directory to find the libraries.

Comment: I updated the question and fixed the errors. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `-Wl,-rpath-link=$LIBPATH` to tell the linker where to look to resolve runtime library references during the link operation.

More info can be found in the `ld` documentation: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.37/ld/Options.html